# Objective-C set constants according to IOS device type

Tags: ios, macros, constants, extern

I created constant file with `Constant.h` and `Constant.m`. I want to set some constants according to device type. I tried following things:

```
//inside Constant.h
extern int FONT;

inside Constant.m
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#ifdef IS_IPAD
    int FONT = 20;
#else
    int FONT = 16;
#enfif
```

but it always taking value 20 not going for 16 even though my device is iPhone.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#ifdef` means "if defined - some value or macro" which is always true because `IS_IPAD` is defined.

There is also an `#if` macro (for example, `#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 30200`) but it is not suitable for your case because `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` will be evaluated at runtime, so you need to use a regular `if` statement.

```
if (IS_IPAD) {
    // ...
}
```

Or the conditional operator `?`:

```
int font = IS_IPAD ? 20 : 16;
```